# Retrieving data from MySQL db

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, c++-cli

So I'm trying to get data from a MySQL database and display it in a messageBox but I don't know how to get the result of the query I made, here's my code:

```
String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password="; /
MySqlConnection^ conDB = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring); 
MySqlCommand^ Query = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT Bar FROM utilizadores.users  WHERE username='"+user+ "' ", conDB ); 
         MySqlDataReader^ reader;
         conDB->Open();
         try 
         {
            reader = Query->ExecuteReader(); 
            MessageBox::Show(/*Result of the Query here*/);
         }
        catch (Exception^ex)
             {
                 MessageBox::Show(ex->Message); 
             }
```

What do I have to put inside the MessageBox to display the result of that query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the data you would typically use code like this. This assumes that Bar is of type double. You can change the type of Bar accordingly. 
The Position of the **bar_value=reader->getDouble(1)** indicates that the result is in the **first** column. 
Accordingly if you retrieved two columns and wanted the value of the second column that was also of type double you could use **second_column=reader->getDouble(2)**

The solution will look similar to this.

```
String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password="; /
MySqlConnection^ conDB = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring); 
MySqlCommand^ Query = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT Bar FROM utilizadores.users  WHERE username='"+user+ "' ", conDB ); 
MySqlDataReader^ reader;
onDB->Open();

double^ bar_value;
String^ messagebox_bar_values;
try 
{
    reader = Query->ExecuteReader(); 
while (reader->Read())
{
    bar_value=reader->GetDouble(1);
    messagebox_bar_values=messagebox_bar_values+bar_value.ToString + ",";

    //Alternatively the line below should also work. If we are not concerned about the datatype and read the value directly as a string.
    //Just comment out the two lines above
    //messagebox_bar_values=messagebox_bar_values+reader["Bar"]->ToString;

}
    MessageBox::Show(messagebox_bar_values);
}
catch (Exception^ex)
{
    MessageBox::Show(ex->Message); 
}
```

A messagebox probably isn't the best way to display this particularly if you have a lot of data, for testing of course it will suffice. A textbox might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
reader = Query->ExecuteReader(); 

String bar = "Bar not found for the user '" & user & "'"

if( reader.Read() ) ' hope the statement returns a single row, and hence `if`
  bar = reader.GetString( 0 )
end if

reader.close()

MessageBox::Show( bar );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but some of that code seems to be in vb.NET instead of C++ CLI, but I understood what you meant and was able to apply it successfuly after converting the code to C++ CLI.